# Google Sign-In authentication

Tags: android, authentication, token, verification, google-signin

I want to integrate Google Sign-In into my Android app, but there's a little bit of confusion. When I receive the ID token from `GoogleSignInAccount`, should I store it on the device and send it to the server with every request as an authentication token? Or is there some other preferred way, i.e. I send the ID token once, then generate some other authentication token on my server, send it to the device, store it on the device and use that as an authentication token. I'm asking because sending the ID token every time is expensive, because it's a pretty long string and its integrity verification on the server side is also time consuming.

Comment: I still don't have the answer. When my app sends the ID token to the server, the server verifies the ID token and gets the actual Google user ID, and what's then? How to authenticate the following requests from my app to the server? How does the server know which user is making the requests?

Comment: Are you building a new auth system or adding Google Sign-In to an existing one? If it's an existing system, then use your current session management; if it's a new system, just use Firebase Auth, which will do session management for you, and give you easy configuration of email / Facebook / Google Sign-In: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/user-auth.html

Comment: Thanks for pointing to Firebase. I'll definitely check it.

Comment: Okay I actually found the Firebase authentication cool and simple, but how do I connect it with my app server? I mean, if I sign-in to my app using Google Sign-in for example, then how do I authenticate with my app server?

Comment: If you use other Firebase services as your backend, then you should be able to make authenticated requests automatically. Otherwise, once you have a user signed in with Firebase Auth (using whatever mechanisms ... Google Sign-In, Facebook, email/password, etc.), then you can get an ID token via <code>FirebaseUser.getToken()</code> containing the user ID to send with authenticated requests to your app server, but remember to verify the token integrity: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/server#verify_id_tokens

Comment: You said "to send with authenticated requests to your app server", but that's exactly what I am asking: HOW TO AUTHENTICATE THOSE REQUESTS.

Comment: When you make a request to your app server, add the ID token string as an Authorization header, then on the server validate the token and apply any application logic to check the current user? Sorry, not sure I understood the question :/

Comment: So I have to send that ID token with every request, right? There is no other appropriate way to authenticate?

Comment: Ya, you'd have to send a token with every request, and check it on every request, as you would for a session cookie on the web. Definitely check out the Firebase data storage services since using those with the provided SDKs would handle most of that for you (and give you a backend for free)

Comment: Can I implement my own backend logic using Firebase?

Comment: Authentication token is a short-lived expiring token. As [this one explains](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/rjR0zYiiEhM), seems like we can use firebase to re-authenticate as it has the refresh token call under the hood. Upon authentication/re-authentication, you can always generate and cache your own server access token to use. Hope this helps you and me.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be sending the authentication token to the server. Why? Because the authentication token is short-lived and after a while the validation with Google will fail when the token expires. The problem is that Google doesn't give any documentation for a refresh token which can be used to regenerate the authentication token.

So suppose you are storing some token on server cache, Firebase Auth helps verify the token ID and regenerate using a refresh token under the hood. Plus on the client, you would now require to send the result from the `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getToken()` task to your server. This token, or another token generated using this, can be safely cached.

I got *why* Firebase Auth [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/rjR0zYiiEhM) and *how* Firebase Auth [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens).